# Is there a way to set how much room the ActionBar needs for the caption

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

When using the Android Actionbar I am doing the following in the onCreateOptionsMenu override:

```
    MenuItem m = menu.add(0, Search, 10, R.string.Search);
    m.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```

It works fine for tablets but on a phone I would like more room as the caption is being shrunk to unacceptable proportions *(Using ActionBarSherlock)*.

Is there a way to specify the minimum caption area so that my caption is a little more meaningful?

Android definition of IsRoom is rather different to mine. :-)

Contrived example below.

[image: Contrived example]

Thanks

Comment: I just stumbled about the same issue. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: not yet. I was hoping the ICS version was more forgiving when it is released.

Comment: The examples you have posted above are exactly what I get wit you app when using it with the latest SDK (api level 14). So there is not improvement. 
BTW: Why are the distances between your buttons different. Photoshop or done by intention? (I currently try to reduce the span between those ActionButtons)

Comment: It's a made up example to illustrate the issue. I did not pay attention to getting it spot on.  I was referring to the source code for ICS as ActionBarSherlock is being recompiled with this and as ICS is phone friendly, the implementation may allow for this issue to be resolved. https://plus.google.com/108284392618554783657/posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock version 4 [has been released](http://jakewharton.com/actionbarsherlock-four-point-oh/) which now supports a much better measuring system for determining how to layout the action bar. I urge you to upgrade so that the above layout will be rendered correctly.

Also, make sure you are not using "always" as your `showAsAction` so that only the correct amount of action items are displayed.

Comment: Thanks Jake. I have been using the beta for some time and completely avoided the issue by using the split action bar.  I am currently trying to update to the final release but cannot find where to download the updated "Plugin: Support Lib" from.